# boost::variant & STL containers - Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm scratching my head on this one. I'm trying to use boost::variant to store a vector of values of which the type is to be determined at run time. The vector's internal type doesn't change once it is known. I am trying to create an interface where my code can add a value to the vector and later I would like to retrieve all the values as a vector. My code will not compile. Is my approach wrong? Should I be using polymorphism for this job? The code is as follows (does not compile):

```
template <typename T>
class record_value_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<void>
{
public:
    record_value_visitor(T v) : _val(v) {}

    void operator()(vector<T>& vec) const
    {
        vec.push_back(this->_val);
    }

private:
    T _val;
};


class monitor
{
public:
    monitor(int type)
    {

        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                this->_values = vector<int>();
                break;
            case 2:
                this->_values = vector<string>();
                break;
            default:
                throw new exception("Invalid type");
        }

        this->_type = type;
    }


    void add_value(int val) 
    { 
        if ( this->_type != 1 ) throw new runtime_error("Invalid type for add_value()");

        boost::apply_visitor( record_value_visitor<int>(val), this->_values);
    }
    void add_value(string val)
    { 
        if ( this->_type != 2 ) throw new runtime_error("Invalid type for add_value()"); 
        boost::apply_visitor( record_value_visitor<string>(val), this->_values);
    }

private:
    int _type;
    boost::variant< vector<int>, vector<double>, vector<string> > _values;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    monitor int_mon(1);
    monitor str_mon(2);

    int_mon.add_value(4);
    str_mon.add_value(string("foo"));


    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Add Error Message

```
    1>c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(832): error C2664: 'void record_value_visitor<T>::operator ()(const std::vector<_Ty> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'T1' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'T1' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<int>,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(173) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(256) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T1,NoBackupFlag>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,NoBackupFlag,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1776) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<first_which,first_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::has_fallback_type_>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=first_which,
1>              step0=first_step
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1787) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1810) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>>(boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\apply_visitor_unary.hpp(76) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::apply_visitor<const Visitor>(Visitor &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=record_value_visitor<int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\documents and settings\g88791\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_boost\test_boost.cpp(58) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::apply_visitor<record_value_visitor<T>,boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>>(const Visitor &,Visitable &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=record_value_visitor<int>,
1>              Visitable=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>
1>          ]
1>c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(832): error C2664: 'void record_value_visitor<T>::operator ()(const std::vector<_Ty> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'T2' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'T2' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<int>,
1>              T=T2
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(173) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T=T2
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(256) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T2,NoBackupFlag>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,NoBackupFlag,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<int>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              T=T2
1>          ]
1>c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(832): error C2664: 'void record_value_visitor<T>::operator ()(const std::vector<_Ty> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'T0' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'T0' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<std::string>,
1>              T=T0
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(173) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T=T0
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(256) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T0,NoBackupFlag>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,NoBackupFlag,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              T=T0
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1776) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<first_which,first_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::has_fallback_type_>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=first_which,
1>              step0=first_step
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1787) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1810) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>>(boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<std::string>
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\apply_visitor_unary.hpp(76) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::apply_visitor<const Visitor>(Visitor &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=record_value_visitor<std::string>
1>          ]
1>          c:\documents and settings\g88791\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_boost\test_boost.cpp(63) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::apply_visitor<record_value_visitor<T>,boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>>(const Visitor &,Visitable &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string,
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<double>,
1>              T2=std::vector<std::string>,
1>              Visitor=record_value_visitor<std::string>,
1>              Visitable=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>
1>          ]
1>c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\variant.hpp(832): error C2664: 'void record_value_visitor<T>::operator ()(const std::vector<_Ty> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'T1' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::string,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'T1' to 'const std::vector<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(145) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<Visitor>::internal_visit<T>(T &,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=const record_value_visitor<std::string>,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(173) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,boost::mpl::false_)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
1>          c:\boost_1_46_1\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(256) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke<Visitor,VoidPtrCV,T1,NoBackupFlag>(int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,T *,NoBackupFlag,int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor<const record_value_visitor<std::string>>,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<std::vector<int>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<std::string>>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              T=T1
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: To be more specific with @Tomalak's point, please post your error message, **verbatim**. Few people have the time to try to cut and paste the code and compile it (especially when it's not guaranteed to reproduce your issue), whereas looking at an exact error message is often enough to tell what's going on.

Comment: As a side comment, I think keeping a separate `type` field is doing it wrong. `boost::variant` has that sort of bookkeeping already.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young In the real program, the type is determined from an ENUM. The monitor class just holds values for data collected from that type. Do you have any suggestions on how you would implement this?

Comment: @playairguitar It's okay to accept the enum in the constructor, but it's redundant to store it as a member -- the variant already does that. If client code needs to access this information, you can provide e.g. a `which()` member which forwards to `boost::variant::which`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compiles and runs as expected:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct record_value_visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    explicit record_value_visitor(T const& val) : val_(val) { }

    void operator ()(std::vector<T>& vec) const
    {
        vec.push_back(this->val_);
    }

    template<typename U>
    void operator ()(std::vector<U> const&) const { /* noop */ }

private:
    T val_;
};

template<typename T>
record_value_visitor<T> make_record_value_visitor(T const& val)
{
    return record_value_visitor<T>(val);
}

struct monitor
{
    explicit monitor(int const type) : type_(type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case 1:
            this->values_ = std::vector<int>();
            break;
        case 2:
            this->values_ = std::vector<std::string>();
            break;
        default:
            throw std::exception("Invalid type");
        }
    }

    void add_value(int const val)
    {
        if (this->type_ != 1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type for add_value()");
        boost::apply_visitor(make_record_value_visitor(val), this->values_);
    }

    void add_value(std::string const& val)
    {
        if (this->type_ != 2)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid type for add_value()");
        boost::apply_visitor(make_record_value_visitor(val), this->values_);
    }

private:
    int type_;
    boost::variant<
        std::vector<int>,
        std::vector<double>,
        std::vector<std::string>
    > values_;
};

int main()
{
    monitor int_mon(1);
    int_mon.add_value(4);

    monitor str_mon(2);
    str_mon.add_value("foo");
}
```

The visitor's `operator()` needs to be callable for every possible type in the variant – the templated `record_value_visitor::operator()` is the key here.